# SQL: How to fill the rows between 2 specific rows with the same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I need to fill/replace the rows with ' - ' between two 'AL' OR two 'MX'  with the value 'AL' or 'MX' depending on where the '-' appears. For the purpose of this example I use only 2 'uid' (i actually have more uid). Besides, the table is ordered by uid and code_date column in ASC

For easy understanding, I have this table:

[image]

but I will like to have something like this:

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2008. Any suggestion on how I can achieve this???

I created the table with the following code:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE
    (uid bigint,
     code_date date,
     Value nchar(10)
    ) 

INSERT  INTO @Customers
VALUES  (1591, '2016-08-01', ''),
    (1591, '2016-08-02', ''),
    (1591, '2016-08-03', 'AL'),
    (1591, '2016-08-04', '-'),
    (1591, '2016-08-05', '-'),
    (1591, '2016-08-06', '-'),
    (1591, '2016-08-07', '-'),
    (1591, '2016-08-08', '-'),
    (1591, '2016-08-09', 'AL'),
    (1591, '2016-08-10', ''),
    (1591, '2016-08-11', 'AL'),
    (1591, '2016-08-12', ''),
    (1082, '2016-02-01', ''),
    (1082, '2016-02-02', ''),
    (1082, '2016-02-03', ''),
    (1082, '2016-02-04', ''),
    (1082, '2016-02-05', 'MX'),
    (1082, '2016-02-06', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-07', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-08', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-09', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-10', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-11', '-'),
    (1082, '2016-02-12', 'MX');

    SELECT * FROM @Customers ORDER BY uid, code_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @x varchar(1000) = ''

update @Customers
set  @x = value = (case when @x <> '' and value not in ('-',@x) then '' else @x end) + (case when value = '-' then '' when value = @x then ''  else value end)
where value <> ''
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/* Test Data & Table */
DECLARE @Customers TABLE
    (Dates datetime,
     Customer integer,
     Value integer) 

    INSERT  INTO @Customers
    VALUES  ('20100101', 1, 12),
        ('20100101', 2, NULL),
        ('20100101', 3, 32),
        ('20100101', 4, 42),
        ('20100101', 5, 15),
        ('20100102', 1, NULL),
        ('20100102', 2, NULL),
        ('20100102', 3, 39),
        ('20100102', 4, NULL),
        ('20100102', 5, 16),
        ('20100103', 1, 13),
        ('20100103', 2, 24),
        ('20100103', 3, NULL),
        ('20100103', 4, NULL),
        ('20100103', 5, 21),
        ('20100104', 1, 14),
        ('20100104', 2, NULL),
        ('20100104', 3, NULL),
        ('20100104', 4, 65),
        ('20100104', 5, 23) ;

/* CustCTE - This gives us a RowNum to allow us to build the recursive CTE CleanCust */
WITH    CustCTE
          AS (SELECT    Customer,
                        Value,
                        Dates,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Dates) RowNum
              FROM      @Customers),

/* CleanCust - A recursive CTE. This runs down the list of values for each customer, checking the Value column, if it is null it gets the previous non NULL value.*/
        CleanCust
          AS (SELECT    Customer,
                        ISNULL(Value, 0) Value, /* Ensure we start with no NULL values for each customer */
                        Dates,
                        RowNum
              FROM      CustCte cur
              WHERE     RowNum = 1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    Curr.Customer,
                        ISNULL(Curr.Value, prev.Value) Value,
                        Curr.Dates,
                        Curr.RowNum
              FROM      CustCte curr
              INNER JOIN CleanCust prev ON curr.Customer = prev.Customer
                                           AND curr.RowNum = prev.RowNum + 1)

/* Update the base table using the result set from the recursive CTE */
    UPDATE trg
    SET Value = src.Value
    FROM    @Customers trg
    INNER JOIN CleanCust src ON trg.Customer = src.Customer
                                AND trg.Dates = src.Dates

/* Display the results */
SELECT * FROM @Customers
```

Comment: @user7020195 This solution did not solve the my question. Am trying to fill the '-' values between the same value 'AL' or 'MX' with either.

Comment: @user7020195 So sorry! The solution was correct. I did not check properly initially. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a `select` query, just use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(t.value, t2.value) as new_value
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.uid = t.uid and t2.code_date < t.code_date and t2.value is not null
      order by t2.code_date desc
     ) t2;
```

You can use similar logic in an `update`.

As an `update`, this would be:

```
update t
    set value = t2.new_value
    from t outer apply
         (select top 1 t2.*
          from t t2
          where t2.uid = t.uid and t2.code_date < t.code_date and t2.value is not null
          order by t2.code_date desc
         ) t2
    where t.value is null;
```